# Difference between h: component and a4j:components?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have search and fetch the following information .
Please add your Information

`h:commandbutton` is same as `a4j:commandButton` the only difference is `a4j:commandButton` have  extra ajax request.

`a4j:commmandButton` is not used for page navigation. 
`h:commandLink` is same as `a4j:commandLink`  the only difference is `a4j:commandLink` have  extra ajax request.

I want to know when we have to use `h:commandButton` ,`a4j:commandButton` ,`h:commmandLink` and `a4j:commandLink`.

What is the difference in `h:commandLink` and `h:outputlink` ?
`h:commandLink` have submit action whereas `h:outputlink` not.

`h:outputLink` is used when we want to navigate from one page to another. 
but for navigation we can use `h:commandlink` also then what are the use of `h:outputLink`?

Answer (score 1):

`h:` tags and the `a4j:` tags are largely similar except the [documentation](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/commandButton.jsf?c=commandButton&tab=usage) for `a4j:` states: (paraphrased slightly)

> a4j: is similar to the standard h:, but
>   produces an Ajax request with a further partial page update.
>   'reRender' attribute points to the component(s) that should be
>   re-rendered in the component tree and updated in the browser DOM after
>   an Ajax Response is completed.

---

**Difference between h: link tags:**

The  renders a fullworthy HTML  element with the proper URL in the href attribute which fires a bookmarkable GET request. It cannot directly invoke a managed bean action method.

```
<h:outputLink value="destination.xhtml">link text</h:outputLink>
```

The  renders a HTML  element with an onclick script which submits a (hidden) POST form and can invoke a managed bean action method. It's also required to be placed inside a .

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="link text" action="destination" />
</h:form>
```

For more about different links: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink) out!